# Problem in Angular Material Drag&Drop CDK when using copyArrayItem

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I am using the `@angular/cdk/drag-drop` module and when I drop in the droplist and when I edit the dropped item, it edits the original item.
Have you an solution about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Moving an array item from another array keeps the memory reference of this item.

If you want to edit the second item but not the first, you need to not use the CDK function.

```js
  const dup = { ...item }; // Be careful, sub objects are still on the same memRef

  secondArray.splice(firstArray.indexOf(item), 0, dup);
```